# Where should I extend prototype of ServerResponse in Sails.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, sails.js

- Sails.js v0.9.4
- Node.js v0.10.18
- Express.js v3.2.6

I have written sails simple web application.
I want to add new function to `ServerResponse` prototype for common error response like following.

#### UtilService.js

```
require('http').ServerResponse.prototype.returnError = function (message) {
    console.error("Error: " + message);
    return this.view("./error", { errors: [{ stack: message }] });
};
```

#### FooController.js

```
require("../services/UtilService");
```

Above codes work well. But I don't write same snippet to all controllers.
How can I keep DRY? In other words, which file should I write above extention code?

---

## Added at 2013-09-25 09:26 UTC

Thank you for advices and suggestions.
I added special logic to `config/bootstrap.js` because I want to run the code for prototype modifying only once.
This looks working fine.

#### config/bootstrap.js

```
module.exports.bootstrap = function (cb) {
  cb();
  require('http').ServerResponse.prototype.returnError = function (message) {
    console.error("Error: " + message);
    return this.view("./error", { errors: [{ stack: message }] });
  };
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thank you for advices and suggestions. I added special logic to `config/bootstrap.js` because I want to run the code for prototype modifying only once. This looks working fine.

#### config/bootstrap.js

```
module.exports.bootstrap = function (cb) {
  cb();
  require('http').ServerResponse.prototype.returnError = function (message) {
    console.error("Error: " + message);
    return this.view("./error", { errors: [{ stack: message }] });
  };
};
```

Comment: Do you know how to extend the ServerResponse prototype when I only have a simple http.Server (without any framework like sails or express).

Answer (score 0):

This seems like a good place to use a policy, since extending the prototype "at the root" as hexacyanide suggests would require altering the express middleware, which I believe is not recommended.

Instead, in `config/policies.js`, try adding a default policy to all actions, e.g.:

```
someController: {
  '*': httpPrototype
}
```

The httpPrototype policy could then look something like this:

```
module.exports = function httpPrototype (req, res, next) {
  require('http').ServerResponse.prototype.returnError = function (message) {
    console.error("Error: " + message);
    return this.view("./error", { errors: [{ stack: message }] });
  };
  next();
};
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion! I want to avoid the execution per every request, so I modified `config/bootstrap.js`. But your suggestion about `policies.js` is really valuable for me.

Comment: Could you share your implementation in another answer and accept it? That way future readers can benefit from your experience here.